# Installing ubuntu on a different partition than C using VMware

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, vmware

I am currently using windows 8.1. I know how to install ubuntu using VMware but this time I want to install it in a different way. I have four physical partitions of my hard disk namely, C,D,E and F. I want to install ubuntu on D drive instead of C using VMware. Please tell me the steps how to do it without affecting my any other partition.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new directory in one of your partitions, say D://VM2016/U16/

Open VMware

Mouse around looking for all the preferences and defaults of where things like virtual machines might be saved and change them to your location in D:
Create a "new virtual machine"
Mouse through all of its settings, making sure that anything points to your location in D:
In particular, make sure that

your "new virtual HDD" .vmdk is in D:

the location to make clone diff files is in D:

the virtual memory swapfile will go to D:

the hibernation file will go to D:

The are still a few lines of configuration done wherever you had installed your /vmware/ so technically it does touch that location, perhaps in /Program Files/, but you can get all of the vm on D: and then start it booting and installing.

Comment: can you upload any pic to show how to perform the last steps?